# C++ Is there any fast way to detect how many std::vector elements has been updated/modified?

Tags: c++, arrays, caching, vector, iterator

I'm currently implementing a caching system that has a similar API to `std::vector`, but it has a member function called `Flush`, which is for transferring elements to somewhere(e.g. hardware, network, etc.).

What I want to do is to make the caching system be able to minimize the transfer overhead through flushing, by just transferring the modified elements instead of the entire array, and also the frequency of transfer should be limited because it needs time cost to initiate a transfer.

What I've tried to do is to inherit `std::vector`, then try to find out if there are any interfaces like `on_element_modified` or `on_element_updated` for me to use to detect if the user modified any of the elements (via `operator[]`, iterators, or `push_back` `insert` `remove`, etc.) then when flushing, I can just transfer these modified elements, but it looks like `std::vector` doesn't have such interfaces for me to use.

```
template<typename Ty, typename Allocator = std::allocator<Ty>>
class MyFlushableVector : public std::vector
{
protected:
    using size_type = typename std::vector::size_type;
    std::vector<bool> updated;
    // These imagined functions is what I need
    void on_element_modified(size_type index) override
    {
        updated[index] = true;
    }
    void on_new_element() override
    {
        updated.push_back(true);
    }
    void on_popped_element() override
    {
        updated.pop_back();
    }
    void Transfer(Ty *Pointer, size_type count)
    {
        // Do some transfer
    }

public:
    void Flush()
    {
        // Minimize the frequency of transfer by finding the updated blocks to transfer.
        size_type i, first_updated = 0;
        bool is_modified = false;
        for (i = 0; i < size(); i++)
        {
            if (is_modified == false)
            {
                if (updated[i])
                {
                    first_updated = i;
                    is_modified = true;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                if (!updated[i])
                {
                    Transfer(data() + first_updated, i - first_updated);
                    is_modified = false;
                }
            }
            updated[i] = false;
        }
        if (is_modified)
        {
            Transfer(data() + first_updated, i - first_updated);
        }
    }
};
```

As I couldn't find these imagination interfaces to use, I'm now trying to implement a new class that isn't inherited from `std::vector` but it has the same interfaces as `std::vector` and I implemented each of them except it doesn't support iterators (because I don't know how to implement an iterator that can detect any write operations to the vector and set the corresponding `updated` element to true). I'm not sure this is the true way to do it in modern C++.

Comment: The vector interface is not good for this. An "evil" user can store a pointer to an element (`int* p = &v[i];`) and use that to change the value later.

Comment: `std::vector` provides no means to detect if an element has been modified.   In fact, by providing unfettered access via pointers (`std::vector.data()`), by reference (e.g. `operator[]()`, iterators) it makes it virtually impossible to detect if an element has been modified.   If you want such a capability, wrap a `std::vector` in a class (inheritance is a really bad idea) and don't expose any pointers or references via that class's interface.   Then provide setters/getters as the only means to access/modify elements - those setters/getters can then be used to track what elements are modified.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The short answer to the question that's contained in the title of this question is simply "no", there's nothing like that, neither in `vector` nor any other C++ library container. If you need to track changes to the values in the container it will be up to you to implement the entire scaffolding that does so.

Other than that, the only other thing you appear to be asking, indirectly, is in the last paragraph which I'll address in the rest of my answer:

> I don't know how to implement an iterator that can detect any
> write operations to the vector and set the corresponding `updated`
> element to true)

I am presuming you're asking how to do that. Well, you can use the same approach that already happens to be used in the C++ library by [`std::ostreambuf_iterator`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/ostreambuf_iterator), which you can simply appropriate for your own purposes.

```
    std::ostreambuf_iterator<char> iter{std::cout};

    *iter++ = 'H';
    *iter++ = 'e';

    // and so on, for the remainder of "Hello world!", which will get written
    // to C++
```

The key factor here is that ***iterators are not pointers***. They are just objects that implement `*` and several other operators (depending on the requirements of the iterator's declared category).

`std::ostreambuf_iterator` implements the `*` and the `++` operator that do ...absolutely nothing. They return the iterator itself. Then, `std::ostreambuf_iterator` also implements the `=` operator, that takes the `char` given to it, and writes it to the output stream buffer.

So, the expression `*iter++` is a big-fat-nothing, it's only there to meet the requirements for this iterator's category, and all the action happens in the `=` operator overload. `*iter++='H';` only actual work that happens is in the invoked `operator=` overload.

Your custom iterator class simply needs to do the same thing: implement an `operator Ty` and `operator=(const Ty&)`. The former hands over the actual `Ty` value that your iterator is referencing. The latter assigns a new value to it, and then sets the corresponding `modified` flag. Your container hands over these iterators, to iterate itself over. The End. Mission accomplished.

Comment: The example of showing how `std::ostreambuf_iterator` works are very informable. It looks like a pointer, but what it does is just put characters into the `ostreambuf`, and obviously that `operator *` and `operator ++` doesn't need to do anything.